# How to cache build data between stages in gitlab-ci?

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have a monorepo project made in typescript and my gitlab pipeline is failing in the test stage.

Here's the error

```
> npx lerna run test
lerna notice cli v3.22.1
lerna info versioning independent
lerna info ci enabled
lerna ERR! TypeError: isPlainObject is not a function
lerna ERR!     at isExtendable (/builds/project/noma-chat-lib/node_modules/mixin-deep/node_modules/is-extendable/index.js:13:10)
lerna ERR!     at isObject (/builds/project/noma-chat-lib/node_modules/mixin-deep/index.js:46:10)
lerna ERR!     at mixinDeep (/builds/project/noma-chat-lib/node_modules/mixin-deep/index.js:10:9)
lerna ERR!     at Snapdragon.Base.initBase (/builds/project/noma-chat-lib/node_modules/base/index.js:70:20)
lerna ERR!     at Snapdragon.Base (/builds/project/noma-chat-lib/node_modules/base/index.js:50:10)
lerna ERR!     at new Snapdragon (/builds/project/noma-chat-lib/node_modules/snapdragon/index.js:23:8)
lerna ERR!     at Object.utils.instantiate (/builds/project/noma-chat-lib/node_modules/@lerna/project/node_modules/micromatch/lib/utils.js:43:18)
lerna ERR!     at parse (/builds/project/noma-chat-lib/node_modules/@lerna/project/node_modules/micromatch/index.js:736:28)
lerna ERR!     at memoize (/builds/project/noma-chat-lib/node_modules/@lerna/project/node_modules/micromatch/index.js:859:13)
lerna ERR! lerna isPlainObject is not a function
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

When I run the same steps as the pipeline on my machine, it works. Also, if I put the test scripts under the build stage it works too. So I think this might be something related to gitlab cache between stages

Here's my **gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: node:16

cache:
  paths:
    - .npm
    - node_modules
    - packages/**/node_modules
    - packages/**/out-tsc
    - dist

stages:
  - config-env
  - build
  - test

config-env:
  stage: config-env
  script:
    - npm install -g npm@latest
    - nodejs -v
    - npm -v
    - npm doctor
  allow_failure: true
  cache:
    paths:
      - .npm
      
lint:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run lint

build:
  except:
    - master
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run build

  artifacts:
    when: on_success
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - node_modules 
      - packages/**/node_modules
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules
      - packages/**/node_modules

unit:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npx jest --clear-cache
    - npm run test
```